# Storing a specific set of numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby

How do you generate some sort of checksum of an array of 5 numbers that would distinguish a set of numbers from another?

For example: 
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] has the same checksum as [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]

I want to generate millions of 5 digit combinations and compare them against a predetermined set of numbers. I want to be able to checksum the ones I generate, and then compare them against a bank of numbers I've already generated.

Let me explain:

- I create an array of numbers as an array
- I generate 6 numbers in an array using Rand()
- I compare the generated numbers to the array I created, exit if they match
- If the numbers don't match, create a hash that I can compare future arrays to. The arrangement of the numbers inside of the array do not matter.

I thought about using an md5sum, but then if the elements change inside, then the md5 would be the same.

I could just store the arrays in memory, but I'm trying to minimize the amount of numbers I store in memory

Comment: You could make use of the `.sort` method perhaps?

Comment: Maybe `Array#hash` is useful?

Comment: You used the term "set" three times, and a fourth time implicitly when you said "The arrangement of the numbers inside of the array do not matter." So, why don't you use a `set`? (Okay, technically speaking, what you describe is a *bag* aka *multiset*, but the same question: why don't you use a bag or multiset instead of an array?)

Comment: There are only 2002 distinct combinations for 5 digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
[1,2,3,4,5].sort.hash #=> 1777030444607087813
[2,3,4,5,1].sort.hash #=> 1777030444607087813
```

should make the sets distinguishable.

Also should be a more memory-friendly solution because

```
5.size #=> 8
1777030444607087813.size #=> 8
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with hashes is that you always need to worry about collisions. Here is a way to make sure each value is unique, (and it's even O(N))

```
require 'prime'
pr = Prime.take(10)
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map{|x| pr[x]}.reduce(&:*)
=> 15015 
[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 1].map{|x| pr[x]}.reduce(&:*)
=> 15015
```

Comment: Worth noting that this only works for lists containing numbers up to M, where M is the number of primes loaded (10, in this example). Still, very clever.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, Yes, the question says 5 _digits_, but you can easily make the `pr` array larger